# A better way to convert a generic ObjectResult collection(Entity Framework datatype) to a Generic List collection?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

Consider the below program

```
 public static void Fill<T1, T2>(ObjectResult<T1> Source, List<T2> Destination)
            where T2 : new()
        {
            Destination.AddRange(Source.Select(CreateMapping<T1, T2>()));
        }

        public static Func<T1, T2> CreateMapping<T1, T2>()
        where T2 : new()
        {
            var typeOfSource = typeof(T1);
            var typeOfDestination = typeof(T2);

            // use reflection to get a list of the properties on the source and destination types
            var sourceProperties = typeOfSource.GetProperties();
            var destinationProperties = typeOfDestination.GetProperties();

            // join the source properties with the destination properties based on name
            var properties = from sourceProperty in sourceProperties
                             join destinationProperty in destinationProperties
                             on sourceProperty.Name equals destinationProperty.Name
                             select new { SourceProperty = sourceProperty, DestinationProperty = destinationProperty };

            return (x) =>
            {
                var y = new T2();

                foreach (var property in properties)
                {
                    var value = property.SourceProperty.GetValue(x, null);
                    property.DestinationProperty.SetValue(y, value, null);
                }

                return y;
            };
        }
```

Where we are accepting an ObjectResult collection(Datatype of Entity Framework) and is returning a generic list . It works fine but in certain situation it throws exception as "object cannot be enumerated twice"...

Is there any better way to re-write the function?

Comment: What are those "certain situations"? Are you by any chance calling `Fill` twice for the same `ObjectResult`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a problem with multiple enumeration of ObjectResult simply don't pass it to your methods and control enumeration yourselves:

```
public static void Fill<T1, T2>(List<T1> Source, List<T2> Destination)
```

and call it with

```
Fill(objectResult.ToList(), destinationList);
```

Btw. why not to use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) instead?